# Jsch renaming file fails

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am uploading a large file by SFTP over Jsch. During the upload process, the old file should be available, so I'm uploading to a temp file and rename it to the new file.

```
final String tmpName = dest + "_tmp";
channel.put(source, tmpName);
channel.rename(tmpName, dest);
```

The upload is ok but the renaming fails:

```
ERROR: Failed to upload files
4: Failure
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2491)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.rename(ChannelSftp.java:1665)
    ...
```

I can't figure out where the problem is. Please help

Comment: Can you post some more details? Whats in "dest"? What permissions are set on dest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The target file already exists. Try deleting the existing file before renaming.

Comment: You're right, deleting the destination file before renaming is the solution. Thanks!

Comment: JSch doesn't use `mv`, it simply sends SFTP commands to a sftp server process (which is either embedded in the ssh server or called by it). This process might be using `mv` or the corresponding syscall directly.

Comment: It seems that you're right. I thought I had seen it in the code, but apparently I'm wrong. Here's the code: http://kickjava.com/src/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.java.htm

Comment: The class is difficult to read. I do not know the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried rename and it worked fine for me. there was another file with same and i tried to rename new file to existing one. and it worked.

so no need to check file exist or not if you want to overwrite.